# Android facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0, how can I remove the login progress bar?

Tags: android, facebook

While using the `loginWithReadPermissions` method of the latest Facebook SDK for Android, a large progress bar is displayed while Facebook waits to either open the app or webview. Is there anyway to stop this progress bar from showing? It is not aesthetically pleasing.

I am using:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
    this,
    Arrays.asList(getResources().getString(R.string.app_facebook_scope_email))
);
```

Comment: No, there isn't, but soon you'll be able set the theme.

Comment: @MingLi what do you mean by *soon*?

Comment: @MingLi could you suggest a version to use that is production ready?  The library also occasionally throws null pointers...com.facebook.login.LoginFragment.onLoginClientCompleted(LoginFragment.java:120)

Comment: The latest version of the Android SDK is 4.1.2, and should have some NPE issues fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Change the `com.facebook.FacebookActivity` entry in your manifest so that it contains:

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"`

instead of

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`

This worked for me.

Comment: This is it. Works like a charm.

Comment: Causes a crash with  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity FacebookActivity did not call finish() prior to onResume() completing.

Comment: Are you trying it on Android 6? I have experienced the crash you mention on devices with M installed. It works on previous versions though.

Comment: More info on why Theme.NoDisplay causes M to crash: https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/LjnRzJKWPGW

Comment: don't forget to add tools:replace="android:theme" in com.facebook.FacebookActivity